# WP Admin register taxonomy and post type performance

Tags: posts, admin, performance, customization

I noticed that the wp backend (admin) gets slower (and slower) when creating custom post types & taxonomies. (note that I'm not flushing any rewrite rules).

Right now I'm calling the register_post_type method every time a page loads (during the init action), but is this really the best way to go? Wouldn't it be enough to just register the cpt once (likes roles)?

Actually I know this is not the case, but it just seems like a huge load every time a page loads.

Can anyone give me some insight on this?

Thanx

Comment: Actually, a post types and taxonomies gets registered twice :-).

Comment: True, I didn't even mention that. Any ideas on the best way to optimize this?

Comment: Did you maybe set hierarchical to true when you registered your post type

Comment: If so, set it to `false`. This will speed things up

Comment: No, but this of course differs per project. I'm just talking about a general 'best-approach'